Einsum abc,cde->abde. How to make sense of it?
I read and understand all simple cases for einsum, such as ab,bc->ac or batched ones like abc,acd->abd.
But "abc,cde->abde" is giving me a hard time. So far I figure there will be a sum on dim "c". What does this einsum mean in matrix multiplication?
If anyone can write a plain matrix multiplication (maybe transpose, seqeeze, ...) will help me understand. Thanks.
I searched online and asked GPT. I expect someone can write a plain matrix multiplication code to replace the einsum shown. This will help me understand.

That's just a traditional matrix multiplication, right?  Last dimension of the first matrix by the first diminsion of the second

^ I can see the dim "C" is common, but could you elaborate how the multiplication works for two 3-dim matrices?

Repeated einsum indices mean that you contract over the repeated dimension. In this case there is a single repeated index, meaning it's effectively equivalent to a simple matrix multiplication of reshaped inputs.
Here's an example:
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.rand(4, 5, 6)
y = np.random.rand(2, 3, 4)

result_einsum = np.einsum('cde,abc->abde', x, y)
result_matmul = (y.reshape(6, 4) @ x.reshape(4, 30)).reshape(2, 3, 5, 6)

np.testing.assert_allclose(result_einsum, result_matmul)


Ah. I think I figure it out. Thanks Tim for the idea. It's just an ordinary matrix multiplication, but of two 3D matrices. Nothing special.
I also found https://math.stackexchange.com/q/917477 has code for a demonstration. Though it's not easy for a direct intuition, but it makes sense.
